# CLI utilities in local Node.js packages

Tags: node.js, npm

Windows 10, Node.js 12.18.3. There's a project (by someone else) - let's call it "foo". It has a dependency on an NPM package called "bar". Bar has a postinstall script with a `lb-clean` command in it. The `lb-clean` command comes from the npm package `@loopback/build`. `Bar` lists `@loopback/build` under `devDependencies` in `package.json`. Yet when I run `npm install` under `foo`, it errors out that `lb-clean` is not found.

If I run `npm install -g @loopback/build`, then `lb-clean.cmd` is installed under %APPDATA%\npm, which is in `PATH`, and the postinstall script is happy.

In a scenario like this, are CLI commands of locally installed dependent packages supposed to be visible on the command line? In other words, is `bar` broken?